# Bulk import m3u8 playlists to Rhythmbox?

Tags: 16.10, rhythmbox, music

How can I batch import about 100 m3u8 playlists into Rhythmbox?

I know I can import them manually, one at a time. This is annoying because I have to type a name for each playlist with each individual import.

I've tried using the petko10 import plugin (https://github.com/petko10/rhythmbox-plugin-playlists-import-export), but it doesn't seem to work. I'm using Rhythmbox 3.4.1 in March 2017, but the plugin hasn't been updated in three years... maybe it no longer works?

I've located an xml file where Rhythmbox saves playlist data (~/.local/share/rhythmbox/playlists.xml), but the file seems to be backup of playlists, not one that Rhythmbox reads to display playlists. When I manually create a playlist entry in the xml file, Rhythmbox doesn't display the playlist.

So... where does Rhythmbox read its playlist information from when it lauches? If I knew the format (assuming it's a writable text format, like xml), I could write a Python script to import my m3u8 playlists if needed.

Thanks!

Ubuntu 16.10. Rhythmbox 3.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in importing m3u8 playlists by bulk renaming their file extensions to "m3u" and then using the petko10 import plugin (https://github.com/petko10/rhythmbox-plugin-playlists-import-export).